Add Outlook.com email account to Outlook Desktop without linking device
I am trying to add an Outlook email address (standard free Microsoft account, @outlook.com, etc) to the Outlook 365 desktop program on Windows 10. However, with a catch - This is a shared account for an organisation, and I really would like to avoid 'linking my device' with this account, whatever that actually means or does.
I believe recently Microsoft has deprecated the ability to use 'Basic Auth' to access email accounts with IMAP, so 'Modern Auth' / OAuth is the only option. In Thunderbird, one can simply add the account as IMAP with OAuth2 authentication, and everything works well. As far as I can tell, Outlook does not support OAuth2 on IMAP accounts, or at least not on Microsoft accounts, so the only way to add the account is as it is autoconfigured, presumably using the MAPI protocol.
When I do this, I get an entry in Windows settings for the account (Settings -> Accounts -> Email & accounts):

And if I login to the Microsoft portal in a browser, my PC & its various details appears under 'Devices'. Removing the account from settings & un-linking online does not break anything initially, but after a while Outlook asks me to login to the account again via the OAuth2 mechanism, and then adds it all back again.
How can I add my Microsoft email account to Outlook without linking my device with the account?
Edit:
Would App Passwords be in any way helpful here?
